# NHibernate .NET for ORACLE 10g “could not execute query”

Tags: nhibernate

this is my code

I want to know want wrong?

```
public IList listdataserviceplan(String custid)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        string query = ” select a.ServicePlanId as ServicePlanId ,
                                a.ServiceDetail as ServiceDetail,”
            + ” a.DateServiceFix as DateServiceFix ,a.DateService as DateService,”
            + ” a.CaseNotSupport as CaseNotSupport ,a.ServiceChangeName as ServiceChangeName,”
            + ” a.DateServiceNew as DateServiceNew ,a.MaterialChange as MaterialChange,”
            + ” a.ServiceGuarantee as ServiceGuarantee ,a.ServiceMaintenance as ServiceMaintenance,”
            + ” a.ServiceCharge as ServiceCharge”
            + ” from BicIsu.Core.Domain.ServicePlan as a”
            + ” where 1=1″
            + ” and a.CustId = ‘” + custid + “‘ ”
            + ” order by a.ServicePlanId”;

        var cons = session.CreateQuery(query).List();
        return cons;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the query work if you run it manually outside of NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the error, but I bet it has something to do with those uber complicated magic strings. Try:

```
string query = @"select a.ServicePlanId, 
                        a.ServiceDetail, 
                        a.DateServiceFix, 
                        a.DateService, 
                        a.CaseNotSupport, 
                        a.ServiceChangeName, 
                        a.DateServiceNew, 
                        a.MaterialChange, 
                        a.ServiceGuarantee, 
                        a.ServiceMaintenance, 
                        a.ServiceCharge  
                from  ServicePlan as a 
                where 1=1 
                and   a.CustId = :custId 
                order by a.ServicePlanId";

var result = session.CreateQuery(query)
                    .SetParameter("custId", custid)
                    .List();
```

FYI, [**Ad-hoc mapping with NHibernate.**](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/06/29/ad-hoc-mapping-with-nhibernate.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+LosTechies+%28LosTechies%29)

Answer (score 0):

probably not the best way to write an hql query. Why dont you use the StringBuilder class.
it will be something like this:

```
var hqlQuery= new StringBuilder();
hqlQuery.Append("select a from ClassA");
hqlQuery.AppendFormat("where a.Id={0}",idVal);

return session.List<ClassA>(hqlQuery.toString());
```

I know this is not the answer. but will definitely help you with the code.

Now wrt to your problem. What is the error that you are getting. Is that query even firing or are you getting an exception?